# Proving continuity in the complex plane using sequences

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

Looking at a question I have recently found, I am completely stumped. I need to prove that the function $f(z) = Re(z)$ is continuous where $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$  using sequences.

I have no clue where to start, can someone help?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|\text{Re}(z)-\text{Re}(w)|\leq|z-w|$, this is a crucial step.

Comment: I understand this but I'm not sure where to proceed from here. Any clues?

Comment: Then you fix a $w$ and let $z_{n}\rightarrow w$, so $|\text{Re}(z_{n})-\text{Re}(w)|\leq|z_{n}-w|\rightarrow 0$, so by Squeeze Theorem, $\text{Re}(z_{n})\rightarrow\text{Re}(w)$.